# How to map Array of Structs in Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, mapping, struct

**Need this architecture**

```
    {
      address1 => [struct1, struct2],
      address2 => [struct1, struct2, struct3,],
      address3 => [struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4, struct5],
      ...
    }
```

**My Attempt**

```
contract Gallery{
uint public emojiCount;
struct Token {
    uint token;
    string ipfsHash;
}
mapping (address => Token[]) public emoji;

function addEmoji (uint _token, string _ipfsHash) public {
   emojiCount ++;
   emoji[msg.sender].push(Token(_token, _ipfsHash));
 }
}
```

How do i return Struct array so that i can save Images `IPFS` `String` according to user account address `[msg.sender]` .

How is this possible in solidity
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code should work as intended, and give you a total count of 'emojis', but you may want that information on a per address basis, to do that you could add a second mapping, to always hold the last position for the inserted address:

```
mapping (address => uint256) addressToLastUsedPosition;
```

then when you do a push on the array, and get the position back, and set the mapping.

```
uint256 newMaxPositionForAddress = emoji[msg.sender].push(Token(_token, _ipfsHash));
addressToLastUsedPostion[msg.sender] = newMaxPositionForAddress;
```

doing so will always allow you to know how many 'emoji' are per address.

Comment: Thank you it's work for me . I think solution you explain with `solidity` code is much easier to understand , where similar question are as mention above are not self explanatory @shaddow

Comment: @shaddow instead of adding a new mapping can we just use 

retrun emoji[msg.sender].length